# How to remove background gray color when using gplot method in Rastervis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-raster, rastervis

Does any one knows that ,how to remove background gray color when using gplot method in Rastervis? I already try to remove the theme color but it did not work.

```
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
s <- stack(r, r*2)
names(s) <- c('meuse', 'meuse x 2')

library(ggplot2)

theme_set(theme_bw())
gplot(s) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
    facet_wrap(~ variable) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'blue') +
    coord_equal() +
    theme(
            plot.background = element_blank()
            ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
            ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
            ,panel.border = element_blank()
            ,panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: see if add theme_bw() works

Comment: already set to the theme_set(theme_bw()), but it did not work. The gray color seems from raster data.

Comment: could you try: gplot(s) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + theme_bw() + ...

Answer (score 4):

Following the link provided by @Bingwei, I found that using `scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'blue', na.value=NA))` works to me. Notice `na.value=NA` instead of `na.value="white"`.

Answer (score 0):

I already got the answer from the author of rasterVis here
https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/issues/13#comments